# ASP.NET SOAP Service - Adding Extra Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have created a simple Web Service to receive data, but I am missing a element, from a client's SOAP sample that I can't seem to emulate.

Below is my Web Service with sample SOAP Layout:

```
[WebMethod]
public void ReceiveStatusUpdate(string Reference, string ThirdPartyReference, string Status)
{
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
            <ReceiveStatusUpdate xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <Reference>string</Reference>
                <ThirdPartyReference>string</ThirdPartyReference>
                <Status>string</Status>
            </ReceiveStatusUpdate>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Below, is their SOAP sample, which has an element called `StatusUpdate`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ReceiveStatusUpdate xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <StatusUpdate>
                <Reference>zzzz</Reference>
                <ThirdPartyReference>yyyy</ThirdPartyReference>
                <Status>xxxx</Status>
            </StatusUpdate>
        </ReceiveCL4UStatusUpdate>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can somebody please explain what I need to add :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the missing element, I needed to declare an object within the service and then each string as a variable within the object, please see my code below:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class Update : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public void ReceiveStatusUpdate(Object StatusUpdate)
        {
            var reference = StatusUpdate.Reference;
            var thirdPartyReference = StatusUpdate.ThirdPartyReference;
            var status = StatusUpdate.Status;
        }

        public class Object
        {
            public string Reference;
            public string ThirdPartyReference;
            public string Status;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this proves useful to others :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the xmlns:soap namespace in "your" example above is missing. It should always have the value of: "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope".

The namespace defines the Envelope as a SOAP Envelope and if a different namespace is used, gernerally, the consuming application generates an error and discards the message.